# Discord.Js - making a bot that creates custom roles

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, undefined, roles

I'm someone who just got into coding recently.

I'm trying to create a Discord bot that can do custom roles that can allow a user of that custom role to edit its hex or name.

There's also the creation of a role creator that also assigns the mentioned user the role.

---

My problem is that I've encountered an issue with the role creation + assignment and the commands that allow the user to edit their role.

Here are the problems:

1. `(node:6288) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` for the role creator command
2. When I try to use the commands that allow the user to customize their roles, the commands don't work, or to be more specific, they don't activate.

I do believe that the codes I'm using could be outdated, therefore if that is the case, please give me the exact location and the right code.
Here are some pictures of the codes. I've pasted the codes below, but I'm a bit new to this forum, so please pay attention to the separating pieces like "Role Customization Code:" to distinguish which one's which. For some reason, the module.exports aren't going in there. Please describe and let me know a solution to these problems in a specific way since I am a newbie at this topic.

[Role creation command + assignment error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6WiN.png)

[Role creation command + assignment code part 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gia3O.png)

[Role creation command + assignment code part 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWPsC.png)

[Role customization code part 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73aop.png)

[Role customization code part 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh9nu.png)

[Role customization code part 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLPmq.png)

Role creation + assignment code:

```js
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const guild = require("./config.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const query = bot.db;

    function embedFail(text) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor("#ff0000").setDescription(text);

        return embed;
    }

    function embedSuccess(text) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor("#7CFC00").setDescription(text);

        return embed;
    }

    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please specify a user to add!");
    let toAdd = message.guild.members.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);

    let rolejoin = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get((val) => val.name.toLowerCase() === rolejoin.toLowerCase());

    if (!toAdd) return message.channel.send("User not found!");
    if (!rolejoin) return message.channel.send("Please specify a role to add!");

    let botRole = message.guild.members.get(bot.user.id).highestRole;

    let isPosition = botRole.comparePositionTo(myRole);
    if (isPosition <= 0) return message.channel.send(embedFail("This role is higher than me, I cannot add this role!"));

    let res = await query(`SELECT * FROM user_roles WHERE role_id='${myRole.id}'`);
    if (res[0]) {
        await query(`DELETE FROM user_roles where role_id='${myRole.id}'`);
        toAdd.removeRole(myRole);
        message.channel.send(embedSuccess(`Removed role ${myRole.name} from ${toAdd.user.username}`));
    } else if (!res[0]) {
        await query(`INSERT INTO user_roles (guild_id, user_id, role_id) VALUES ('${message.guild.id}',${toAdd.id},'${myRole.id}')`);
        toAdd.addRole(myRole);
        message.channel.send(embedSuccess(`Adding role ${myRole.name} to ${toAdd.user.username}`));
    }
};
```

Role Customization Code:

```js
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const guild = require("./config.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, db) => {
    const query = bot.db;

    function embedFail(text) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor("#ff0000").setDescription(text);

        return embed;
    }

    function embedSuccess(text) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setColor("#7CFC00").setDescription(text);

        return embed;
    }

    let res = await query(`SELECT * FROM user_roles WHERE guild_id = '${message.guild.id}' AND user_id = '${message.author.id}'`);

    if (!args[0]) {
        if (!res[0]) return message.channel.send(embedFail("You do not have a role!"));

        let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(res[0].role_id);

        let assignNames = "";
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`Current role assigned to ${message.author.username}`, message.guild.iconURL)
            .setColor(myRole.hexColor)
            .addField(`Name`, `${myRole.name}`, true)
            .addField(`Colour`, `${myRole.hexColor}`, true);

        message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
        if (!res[0]) return message.channel.send(embedFail("You do not have a role!"));

        let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(res[0].role_id);
        if (!myRole) {
            await query(`DELETE FROM user_roles where guild_id = '${message.guild.id}' AND role_id = '${res[i].role_id}' and user_id = '${res[i].user_id}'`);
            return message.channel.send(embedFail("You do not have a role!"));
        }

        switch (args[0]) {
            case "name":
                let name = args.slice(1).join(" "),
                    oldName = myRole.name;
                await myRole.setName(name);
                await message.channel.send(embedSuccess(`You have changed ${oldName}'s name to ${name}!`));
                break;

            case "color":
            case "color":
                let hexCode = args[1],
                    oldHex = myRole.hexColor;
                await myRole.setColor(hexCode);
                await message.channel.send(embedSuccess(`You have changed ${myRole.name}'s color from ${oldHex} to #${hexCode}!`));
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of the code. Post the code so it is easier for us to debug your code and come up with a solution.

Comment: Edited it to provide codes at the bottom. However, I'm a bit new to this forum, so some bits of the code isn't in the code format despite me pasting it in there. Hopefully, both the code insert and pictures provide support.